# Is a conforming implementation impossible on a system with no monotonic clock?

Tags: c++, time, c++11, implementation, c++-chrono

The `<chrono>` header defines class `steady_clock` that represents a monotonic clock - that is, the value of `now()` never decreases as physical time increases. This class isn't marked as optional though, so what happens if the implementation can't implement it because it is running on a system with no monotonic time source?

Taking a look at the libstdc++ source, in the case of `_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC` not being defined, `steady_clock` is simply defined by:

```
typedef system_clock steady_clock;
```

`system_clock` isn't necessarily steady though, so this may (and probably will) break the requirements of `steady_clock`.

Is a conforming implementation of C++11 impossible on a system with no monotonic time source? Why not just make `steady_clock` optional like the `intX_t` types?

Comment: Are there systems where implementing a monotonic clock is not possible?

Comment: Damn, now I think it's a dumb question. I guess I just assumed so.

Comment: Yes there are such systems. I have one that has to make do with no time source whatsoever.

Comment: This is now equivalent to asking "Is a conforming implementation impossible on a tomato?"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Well there you go. Put that as the answer.

Comment: You can always just increment a counter. The counter is as stable as whatever you can use to do periodic increments, but it can be monotonic.

Comment: @nos: Integer overflow would have killed it. Such systems are probably 16 bit so the clock overflows too fast (mine is actually 8 bit so even using int instead of byte (typedef of unsigned char) is a bad idea).

Comment: @Joshua You can do 64 bit arithmetic on a 16 bit processor, or 16 bit on an 8 bit processor, just as you can do 64 bit arithmetic on a 32 bit x86.

Comment: @nos: No point. The compiler did not have a data type for 64 bit integers.

Comment: On top of the accepted answer, implementing a monotonic clock even on systems without a stable clock could work: have `steady_clock` keep track of the last returned time value. If the current value is "before" that then simply return the last value. Granted, it's not ideal, but the value of `now()` would never decrease as physical time increases.

Comment: @Joshua The point is you can do the 16 bit math, or whatever you need, yourself - you don't need a data type for it , we counted to more than 255 on computers before there was 16 bit processors. though it will not be an arithmetic type, I believe <chrono> only requires it to behave like one (i.e. you can wrap the counter in a class with the proper operator overloads)

Comment: Forget it. It turns out we cheaped out and didn't add the clock divider required for the timer interrupt to work so none of that would have helped at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose that such a system would be some kind of embedded system.

Well, such <strike>systems</strike> tomatoes can have freestanding implementations, which only require a minimal subset of the standard library. `<chrono>` is not a part of that minimal subset.

This is defined in §17.6.1.3 Freestanding implementations [compliance]:

> *1* Two kinds of implementations are defined: *hosted* and *freestanding* (1.4). For a hosted implementation, this
>   International Standard describes the set of available headers.
>
> *2* A freestanding implementation has an implementation-defined set of headers. This set shall include at least
>   the headers shown in Table 16.

Table 16 contains the following headers: `<ciso646>`, `<cstddef>`, `<cfloat>`, `<limits>`, `<climits>`, `<cstdint>`, `<cstdlib>`, `<new>`, `<typeinfo>`, `<exception>`, `<initializer_list>`, `<cstdalign>`, `<cstdarg>`, `<cstdbool>`, `<type_traits>`, and `<atomic>`.

Note that this does not mean that such an implementation cannot provide a `<chrono>` header with everything that can be implemented in it, but not the rest.